# Dynamically population FROM email address through exactTarget API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using .NET API to send emails through exactTarget.  I am able to dynamically create emails with dynamic contents for each of the recipients (subscribers). But I am struggling to update FROM Email address. Every time I send an email it uses the default sender profile.  I need some guidance or code snippet on dynamically creating/updating from Email address in ExactTarget.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
- Ahmed

Comment: Are you creating a Sender Profile, and then creating an EmailSendDefinition?

Comment: Hi Timothy - I am still trying to figure this out if I should create Sender Profile before EmailSendDefinition.  I did try to create Sender Profile before creating EmailSendDefinition but it didn't work. I got error when trying to create the sender profile. The error didn't tell me as what went wrong. it is very generic.  So far the working code I have does this... I create a subscriber list, then I create an email. Finally I create a SEND and add the subscriber list and the email to the SEND. This seems to work fine. I just need to find a way to update the FROM email address.